# Crystal Report 2008 swap data table for identical differently-named table

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I have a Crystal Report that gets its data from a SQL Server view.  The users want the view to be able to get data from a particular start/end date range which means the view needs parameters passed to it.

I have put the view's query into a SQL Server stored procedure with parameters.

I was able to get the Crystal Report in question to use that SP as part of its data and it prompts for the start/end dates just fine.

I have gone through the formula fields and was able to modify the formulas to point to the corresponding fields in the SP's data in stead of the view.

I need to somehow get the fields that are displaying in the details section of the report and other areas to utilize data from the new SP and not from the view.

I'd like to modify each control and field on the Crystal Report layout to somehow change the tablename of those fields from (CurrentTableName).(FieldName) to (NEWTableName).(FieldName).  I think this would be the least intrusive because I think some of the fields being used have formatting and other attributes added to them and I don't want to do a whole bunch of detective work.

I know in other development products there is usually a properties window where you can find the TableName.FieldName for an object in the report and you can just edit it to be NEWTableName.FieldName.

Comment: Thats nothing to do with SQL Server...

Comment: Agreed.  I'm trying to modify each Crystal Report field that is displayed on the Crystal Report.  I've used a different product in the past and that product allowed me to change the tablename portion of "tablename.fieldname" in the report layout.

Comment: You can remap entire table - Database, Set datasource location. Pretty usable when replacing underlying views or tables or SP.  You can't remap single fields however.

Comment: I tried this yesterday and it did not work.  After seeing your suggestion I was willing to try it again today (thinking it would still not work) ... I learned today that IT HELPS TO --READ--.  Yesterday's problem was between the keyboard and the chair.  Your suggestion worked.  However for some reason ... even though the SP puts out the EXACT SAME OUTPUT that the view did ... the CR says "one or more fields could not be found in the result set" it appears because the original "database / show sql" was quering the view but adding its own fields to the select list whereas it is now not.